# iOS camera preview is unstable

Tags: ios, camera, metal, frame-rate, avcapturesession

Apple provides a sample iOS project called [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) where they use an [MTKView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview) to render the camera preview to the screen. The problem is that the frame duration - the amount of time each individual camera frame spends being displayed on the screen - is not stable. The camera stream is running at 30 FPS, that is one frame delivered every 33.3 milliseconds, so it stands to reason that we should be able to display these frames one after another with a frame duration of 33.3 ms. In reality the frame duration is unstable - most of the time it is about 33.3 ms but sometimes it is roughly 16.7 or 50.1 ms.

According to documentation the default behavior for MTKView is to draw to the screen at 60 FPS, that is one frame every 16.7 ms, so each camera frame would be drawn twice before it is replaced by the next one. The fact that MTKView’s draw loop and the camera’s capture loop are not synchronized explains the problem - the time elapsed between a draw and a capture will gradually drift causing frames to go from being captured just before a draw to just after a draw and so on and so forth resulting in some frames being displayed for three draws or one draw instead of the expected two. The MTKView draw loop can be synchronized with the camera by disabling the default behavior and manually calling draw whenever a new camera frame arrives, but all of this is still not synchronized with the device display itself which is rendering at 60 FPS in its own loop. So, we still have the same fundamental timing problem. I know [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) is meant for synchronizing things to the display but there is no way for the capture stream to use it.

So how do we render the camera preview with a stable 33.3 ms frame duration? Is the instability an expected behavior with no workaround?

---

**Edit**

Some observations on the behavior of the AVCamFilter project with different MTKView settings. In all cases the *total display time* of a camera frame - `frame duration * draws per frame` - is not stable at 33.3 ms.

- Original source code: frame duration is 16.7, draws per frame is 1, 2, or 3.
- `preferredFramesPerSecond = 30`: frame duration is 33.3 with infrequent bursts of 16.7 or 50.1, draws per frame is 1 or 2, frequent dropped (overwritten) frames.
- Same as above, `commandBuffer.present(drawable, afterMinimumDuration: 1.0 / 30.0)`: frame duration is 33.3, draws per frame is 1 or 2, infrequent dropped (overwritten) frames.
- `isPaused = true`, manually `draw()` when a new camera frame is delivered: frame duration is 16.7, 33.3, 50.1, or 66.9, draws per frame is 1.
- Same as above, `commandBuffer.present(drawable, afterMinimumDuration: 1.0 / 30.0)`: frame duration is 33.3, 50.1, or 66.9, draws per frame is 1.

Comment: If you need to match the FPS of another stream, you can use `presentAfterMinimumDuration`

Comment: Yes, it does create a stable frame duration but this is misleading because it comes at the cost of occasionally dropping a frame. If you think about it this makes sense - the drift between camera and display mentioned above means you will eventually end up in a situation where the camera has delivered a new frame just before it can display the previous frame, at which point you must either overwrite (drop) the previous frame or put the new frame into a queue making the stream lag. I've confirmed this programmatically and visually.

Comment: There's always a possibility of dropping frames, because your application doesn't live in a vacuum, there's other stuff going on on the device.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the need to drop is explicitly caused by the time difference between frame capture and frame display gradually shifting further apart over time. I would think that is something we should be able to prevent.

Comment: You can use `CADisplayLink` or `CVDisplayLink` to get a high-priority callback exactly at display sync intervals. That doesn't matter though that you won't drop frames. Screen and camera just live on different timelines and you have to deal with that in some way.

Comment: I can certainly use it to synchronize the MTKView draw with the display, but the camera cannot use it to drive its own capture stream loop, so we still have the same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly, you expect the camera (**AVCaptureSession**) to produce sample buffer at rate of 30fps and expect **MTKView** to consume these images at exactly the same rate of 30fps to render them to the screen.

**MTKView will not guarantee** that `drawInMTKView` will always be called at 30 fps. For various reasons, the callback to `drawInMTKView` may incidentally be skipped. The Same is true for
**AVCaptureSession**.

Comment: I have verified camera capture and MTKView draws occurring at their expected FPS during my testing. There is some flakiness when the camera stream first starts but it quickly normalizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run draw calls of `MTKView` at specific framerate, why not try `preferredFramesPerSecond` property?

**As per apple doc:**

> When your application sets its preferred frame rate, the view chooses
> a frame rate as close to that as possible based on the capabilities of
> the screen the view is displayed on. To provide a consistent frame
> rate, the actual frame rate chosen is usually a factor of the maximum
> refresh rate of the screen. For example, if the maximum refresh rate
> of the screen is 60 frames per second, that’s also the highest frame
> rate the view sets as the actual frame rate. However, if you ask for a
> lower frame rate, the view might choose 30, 20, or 15 frames per
> second, or another factor, as the actual frame rate. Your application
> should choose a frame rate that it can consistently maintain. The
> default value is 60 frames per second.

This does solve the issue of sync as per my observation when worked on live filters on camera feed.

Also, I don't know if got your problem correctly, because in theory if you are using latest available frame from `AVCapture` session in your rendering cycle, no matter at what FPS it runs, you should not see any hiccups unless your rendering is not staying steadily at the same framerate, or if it goes below camera capture framerate.

Comment: I experimented with that but matching FPS isn’t the issue. If the display and the camera were both running at 60 FPS we still have a problem because neither is producing frames at precisely 1/60 ms intervals. There is always some minuscule error and this accumulates over time causing one loop to drift further out of sync with the other. Without a way to stay synchronized it seems that Camera -> MTKView -> Display really need to be unified into a single loop.